# swift multiple MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: xcode, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

hi I'm playing with the MPMoviePlayerController in swift
i have 2 MPMoviePlayerControllers I preload video in to each in view did load the second one plays from a button fine the first will play after the second has played? if I load the first one i get sound no picture but if play the second one then the first will then play fine?
here is a link to my testing

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22927/videotest.zip

thanks for your help

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer


class ViewController: UIViewController
{
     var moviePlayer : MPMoviePlayerController!
        var moviePlayer2 : MPMoviePlayerController!

    @IBOutlet weak var movieview: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var movieview2: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        loadMovie()
        loadMovie2()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    @IBAction func play2(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        moviePlayer2.play()
    }

    @IBAction func playbtn(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        moviePlayer.play()
    }
    func loadMovie()
    {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video1", ofType:"mp4")
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: movieview.frame.size.width, height: movieview.frame.size.height )
    moviePlayer.view.sizeToFit()
    moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.Fill
    moviePlayer.fullscreen = false
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
    moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File
    moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.None
    moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
    moviePlayer.pause()
    movieview.addSubview( moviePlayer.view)
    }  
    func loadMovie2()
    {


        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video2", ofType:"mp4")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        moviePlayer2 = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        moviePlayer2.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: movieview2.frame.size.width, height: movieview2.frame.size.height )
        moviePlayer2.view.sizeToFit()
        moviePlayer2.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.Fill
        moviePlayer2.fullscreen = false
        moviePlayer2.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
        moviePlayer2.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File
        moviePlayer2.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.None
        moviePlayer2.prepareToPlay()
        moviePlayer2.pause()
        movieview2.addSubview( moviePlayer2.view)
    }






}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AssetsLibrary
import MediaPlayer
import CoreMedia

var player : AVPlayer? = nil
var playerLayer : AVPlayerLayer? = nil
var asset : AVAsset? = nil
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem? = nil

var loadingAssetOne = false

@IBOutlet weak var movieview: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
@IBAction func play2(sender: AnyObject)
{
     loadingAssetOne = false
     loadMovie()
}

@IBAction func playbtn(sender: AnyObject)
{
     loadingAssetOne = true
     loadMovie()
}
func loadMovie()
{

  if loadingAssetOne 
  {
   let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video1", ofType:"mp4")
   let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
   asset = AVAsset(URL: url) as AVAsset

   playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset!)
   player = AVPlayer (playerItem: self.playerItem!)
   playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
   movieview.frame = CGRectMake(38, 57, 220, 106) 
   playerLayer?.frame = movieview.frame
   movieview.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)

   player!.play()
 }
 else
 {
   let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video1", ofType:"mp4")
   let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
   asset = AVAsset(URL: url) as AVAsset

   playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset!)
   player = AVPlayer (playerItem: self.playerItem!)
   playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
   movieview.frame = CGRectMake(38, 206, 220, 106) 
   playerLayer?.frame = movieview.frame
   movieview.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)

   player!.play()
 }
}
```

For more details,please go through the below source

[Need to show multiple video using MPMoviePlayerController swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831496/need-to-show-the-image-of-video-in-mpmovieplayercontroller-swift/34000470#34000470)