# Need to show the image of video in mpmovieplayercontroller swift

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, avasset

I have already asked this doubt in my co workers profile, but no solution yet get. Please help me to solve this problem. i am struck more than 4 hours.

So far i did:

I use to choose the video from gallery and display that in screen using  `mpmovieplayercontroller`. Here i am choosing 2 video  one by one. If i select first video and to display and when i move to load second video my first video screen is in `black`. But i need to display the video image in that player. How to do that.please help me out

My code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MobileCoreServices
import AssetsLibrary
import MediaPlayer
import CoreMedia

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    var Asset1: AVAsset?
    var Asset2: AVAsset?
    var Asset3: AVAsset?
    var audioAsset: AVAsset?
    var loadingAssetOne = false

// swt duplicate image for thumbnail image for audio
    @IBOutlet weak var musicImg: UIImageView!

    var videoPlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()
var mediaUI = UIImagePickerController()
    var videoURL = NSURL()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        musicImg.hidden = true
        let gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapGesture")

        gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        videoPlayer.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)


    }


    func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        //location = gestureRecognizer .locationInView(videoPlayer.view)
        print("tapped")
    }

    //#pragma mark - gesture delegate
    // this allows you to dispatch touches

    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {

        return true

    }

   func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
        shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            return true


    }







    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func startMediaBrowserFromViewController(viewController: UIViewController!, usingDelegate delegate : protocol<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>!) -> Bool {

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.SavedPhotosAlbum) == false {
            return false
        }

        let mediaUI = UIImagePickerController()
        mediaUI.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum



        mediaUI.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        mediaUI.allowsEditing = true
        mediaUI.delegate = delegate
        presentViewController(mediaUI, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return true
    }


// after merge all video and audio. the final video will be saved in gallery and also will display like preview
    func exportDidFinish(session: AVAssetExportSession) {
        if session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed {
            let outputURL = session.outputURL
            let library = ALAssetsLibrary()
            if library.videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL) {
                library.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL,
                    completionBlock: { (assetURL:NSURL!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

                        if error != nil {

                            print("some files went wrong")

                        } else {

                            // get the output url to display the final video in screen
                            self.videoURL = outputURL!

                            self.mediaUI.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                            self.videoPlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()
                            self.videoPlayer.contentURL = self.videoURL


                            self.videoPlayer.controlStyle = .Embedded

                            self.videoPlayer.scalingMode = .AspectFill

                            self.videoPlayer.shouldAutoplay = true

                            self.videoPlayer.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
                            self.videoPlayer.fullscreen = true
                            self.videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(38, 442, 220, 106)

                            self.view.addSubview(self.videoPlayer.view)

                            self.videoPlayer.play()
                            self.videoPlayer.prepareToPlay()

                        }

                })
            }
        }


        Asset1 = nil
        Asset2 = nil
        Asset3 = nil
        audioAsset = nil
    }



    // click first video
    @IBAction func FirstVideo(sender: AnyObject) {
                  loadingAssetOne = true
            startMediaBrowserFromViewController(self, usingDelegate: self)

    }

// clcik second video
    @IBAction func SecondVideo(sender: AnyObject) {

            loadingAssetOne = false
            startMediaBrowserFromViewController(self, usingDelegate: self)

    }
   // click audio
    @IBAction func Audio(sender: AnyObject) {

        let mediaPickerController = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .Any)
        mediaPickerController.delegate = self
        mediaPickerController.prompt = "Select Audio"
        presentViewController(mediaPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }







    @IBAction func playPreview(sender: AnyObject) {

         startMediaBrowserFromViewController(self, usingDelegate: self)
    }




    // orientation for the video
    func orientationFromTransform(transform: CGAffineTransform) -> (orientation: UIImageOrientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
        var assetOrientation = UIImageOrientation.Up
        var isPortrait = false
        if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .Right
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .Left
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .Up
        } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .Down
        }
        return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
    }

    func videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
        let assetTrack = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

        let transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
        let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform)

        var scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.width
        if assetInfo.isPortrait {
            scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
            let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleToFitRatio, scaleToFitRatio)
            instruction.setTransform(CGAffineTransformConcat(assetTrack.preferredTransform, scaleFactor),
                atTime: kCMTimeZero)
        } else {
            let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleToFitRatio, scaleToFitRatio)
            var concat = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(assetTrack.preferredTransform, scaleFactor), CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 2))
            if assetInfo.orientation == .Down {
                let fixUpsideDown = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
                let windowBounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
                let yFix = assetTrack.naturalSize.height + windowBounds.height
                let centerFix = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(assetTrack.naturalSize.width, yFix)
                concat = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(fixUpsideDown, centerFix), scaleFactor)
            }
            instruction.setTransform(concat, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
        }

        return instruction
    }
   // merge all file
    @IBAction func MergeAll(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let firstAsset = Asset1, secondAsset = Asset2 {

            let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

            //load first video
            let firstTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo,
                preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
            do {
                try firstTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration),
                    ofTrack: firstAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] ,
                    atTime: kCMTimeZero)
            } catch _ {
            }
            // load second video
            let secondTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo,
                preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
            do {
                try secondTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration),
                    ofTrack: secondAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] ,
                    atTime: firstAsset.duration)
            } catch _ {
            }


            let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
            mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(firstAsset.duration, secondAsset.duration))

            let firstInstruction = videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(firstTrack, asset: firstAsset)
            firstInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, atTime: firstAsset.duration)
            let secondInstruction = videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(secondTrack, asset: secondAsset)

            mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [firstInstruction, secondInstruction]
            let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
            mainComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
            mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
            mainComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)

            //load audio
            if let loadedAudioAsset = audioAsset {
                let audioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: 0)
                do {
                    try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(firstAsset.duration, secondAsset.duration)),
                        ofTrack: loadedAudioAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0] ,
                        atTime: kCMTimeZero)
                } catch _ {
                }
            }

          // save the final video to gallery
            let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .LongStyle
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
            let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
            // let savePath = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("mergeVideo-\(date).mov")

         let savePath = (documentDirectory as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("final-\(date).mov")

            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: savePath)


            let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
            exporter!.outputURL = url
            exporter!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
            exporter!.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
            exporter!.videoComposition = mainComposition

            exporter!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler() {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.exportDidFinish(exporter!)
                })
            }
        }
    }

}

extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {



    // display the first & second video after it picked from gallery
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie {

            let avAsset = AVAsset(URL: info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL)

            if loadingAssetOne {

                if let vURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
                    self.videoURL = vURL
                } else {
                    print("oops, no url")
                }
                mediaUI.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                self.videoPlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()
                self.videoPlayer.contentURL = videoURL
                self.videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(38, 57, 220, 106)
                self.view.addSubview(self.videoPlayer.view)

                self.videoPlayer.controlStyle = .Embedded

                self.videoPlayer.scalingMode = .AspectFill


                self.videoPlayer.shouldAutoplay = true
                self.videoPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                self.videoPlayer.play()


                Asset1 = avAsset
            } else {

                if let vURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
                    self.videoURL = vURL
                } else {
                    print("oops, no url")
                }
                mediaUI.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                self.videoPlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()
                self.videoPlayer.contentURL = videoURL
                self.videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(38, 206, 220, 106)
                self.view.addSubview(self.videoPlayer.view)
                self.videoPlayer.play()

                self.videoPlayer.controlStyle = .Embedded

                self.videoPlayer.scalingMode = .AspectFill


                self.videoPlayer.shouldAutoplay = true
                self.videoPlayer.prepareToPlay()


                Asset2 = avAsset
            }

        }


}


}






extension ViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

}

extension ViewController: MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate {
    func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {
        let selectedSongs = mediaItemCollection.items
        if selectedSongs.count > 0 {
            let song = selectedSongs[0]


            if let vURL = song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? NSURL {
                audioAsset = AVAsset(URL: vURL)

                dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


                mediaUI.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                      musicImg.hidden = false


                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "yes", message: "Audio Loaded", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler:nil))
                presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No audio", message: "Audio Not Loaded", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler:nil))
                presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } else {
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func mediaPickerDidCancel(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I need to show the image of selected video in screen.Please help me to resolve,Thanks

I follow this link tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/94404/play-record-merge-videos-ios-swift)

Comment: please can any one help me for this

Comment: When do you want to solve this?

Comment: @user3182143 this problem will solve ??

Comment: Wait I will try to solve this.

Comment: Where did you add the delegate and extension class in your view controller? I mean did you add the separate class for delegate and extension?

Comment: no i haven't add any delegate or extesion in separate class

Comment: where did you add this extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate in your view controller?

Comment: see my updated post thats is my full code in viewcontroller

Comment: Better to send me your project.I will rectify that.

Comment: can u give me your mail id

Comment: is it possible to send your email id?

Comment: I sent you the mail please check it.

Comment: Mark please check the mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want to play more than one video in same view, you can use AVPlayer of AVFoundation.I have read more about this in StackOverflow and AppleDoucument and Other forums.All they say is not possible using MPMoviePlayerViewController.But it is possible using AVPlayer.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MobileCoreServices
import AssetsLibrary
import MediaPlayer
import CoreMedia

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
var optionalInteger: Int?
var Asset1: AVAsset?
var Asset2: AVAsset?
var Asset3: AVAsset?
var audioAsset: AVAsset?
var loadingAssetOne = false


@IBOutlet weak var musicImg: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var videoView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var videoViewTwo: UIView!

var player : AVPlayer? = nil
var playerLayer : AVPlayerLayer? = nil
var asset : AVAsset? = nil
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    musicImg.hidden = true
    let gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapGesture")

    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    videoPlayer.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    imageViewVideoOne.hidden = true
    imageViewVideoTwo.hidden = true
}
func startMediaBrowserFromViewController(viewController: UIViewController!, usingDelegate delegate : protocol<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>!) -> Bool 
{

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.SavedPhotosAlbum) == false {
        return false
    }

    let mediaUI = UIImagePickerController()
    mediaUI.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum



    mediaUI.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
    mediaUI.allowsEditing = true
    mediaUI.delegate = delegate
    presentViewController(mediaUI, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return true

}
 // click first video
@IBAction func FirstVideo(sender: AnyObject) {
        loadingAssetOne = true
         optionalInteger = 0
        startMediaBrowserFromViewController(self, usingDelegate: self)

}

// clcik second video
@IBAction func SecondVideo(sender: AnyObject) {

        loadingAssetOne = false
        optionalInteger = 1
        startMediaBrowserFromViewController(self, usingDelegate: self)

}
// click audio
@IBAction func Audio(sender: AnyObject) {

    let mediaPickerController = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .Any)
    mediaPickerController.delegate = self
    mediaPickerController.prompt = "Select Audio"
    presentViewController(mediaPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
 @IBAction func playPreview(sender: AnyObject) 
 {
    startMediaBrowserFromViewController(self, usingDelegate: self)
 }
 extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate 
 {

    // display the first & second video after it picked from gallery
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) 
    {
      let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString
      dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

      if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie 
      {
        if loadingAssetOne 
        {
          let avAsset = AVAsset(URL: info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL)
          print(avAsset)
            if let vURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
                self.videoURL = vURL

            } else {
                print("oops, no url")
            }
            mediaUI.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  let videoURLWithPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL
            self.videoURL = videoURLWithPath!
            asset = AVAsset(URL: videoURL) as AVAsset

            playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset!)
            player = AVPlayer (playerItem: self.playerItem!)
            playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
            videoView.frame = CGRectMake(38, 57, 220, 106)
            playerLayer?.frame = videoView.frame
            videoView.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)

            player!.play()
        } 
        else 
        {
           let avAssetTwo = AVAsset(URL: info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL)
            print(avAssetTwo)
           if let vURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
                self.videoURL = vURL
            } else {
                print("oops, no url")
            }
            mediaUI.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
          let videoURLWithPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL
           self.videoURL = videoURLWithPath!
           asset = AVAsset(URL: videoURL) as AVAsset

            playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset!)
            player = AVPlayer (playerItem: self.playerItem!)
            playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
            videoView.frame =  CGRectMake(38, 206, 220, 106)
            playerLayer?.frame =  videoView.frame
            videoView.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)
            player!.play()
           }
         }
       }
 }
```

Sources for your question

[Multiple Video same screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828256/multiple-video-same-screen)

[Multiple Video Playback on iOS](http://iosguy.com/2012/01/11/multiple-video-playback-on-ios/)

[Apple MPMoviePlayerViewController Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html)

[Playing Multiple Video Simultaneously](http://www.sdkboy.com/2011/07/video-on-the-iphone-tutorial-part-3-playing-multiple-videos-simultaneously/)

[Apple AVPlayer Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html)

[Playing Multiple Videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082206/play-multiple-videos)

[Playback](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html)

[Playing Video in iOS](http://jacopretorius.net/2013/02/playing-video-in-ios.html)