# getting crash and not getting json data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

i use to get data from this url api.but i checked this in my console but it getting crash.It like get the movie list and to display in table view.Here i use to  check whether i am doing in correct way or in wrong manner.

Here my code:

**EDITED:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *authUrl =@"http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Game%20of%20Thrones&Season=1";

    NSString *str1 = [authUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str1];
    NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError * error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
    NSLog(@"json%@",json);
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and show the last line where the code is executed - it will help and you may find the problem yourself

Comment: Hey Mark, I would recommend you to use AFNetworking for server communication. You could easily track success and failure blocks, and see what could be possible problem...

Comment: yes, but i haven't use AFNetworking before. is there any sample code or project for this type of getting data and to display that.

Comment: Try this way `NSMutableArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
` @mark

Comment: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: @dharmesh getting crash `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe7024439d0'
`

Comment: @stefan that link is for AFNetworking library file or its a full demo project that they used AfNetworking !

Comment: I Get Response Please check my code @mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Got Your solution.

Just Replace my code in your code.

And in console you saw result..

```
 NSString *authUrl =@"http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Game of Thrones&Season=1";

NSString *str1 = [authUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str1];
NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError * error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
NSLog(@"json%@",json);
```

**In Console**

```
json{
    Search =     (
                {
            Poster = "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTgxOTI4NzY2M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMjY3MTM2NDE@._V1_SX300.jpg";
            Title = "Game of Thrones";
            Type = series;
            Year = "2011\U2013";
            imdbID = tt0944947;
        },
                {
            Poster = "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjE5NTk5NDg3OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDExNzg2MDE@._V1_SX300.jpg";
            Title = "Game of Thrones";
            Type = game;
            Year = 2012;
            imdbID = tt2231444;
        },
                {
            Poster = "N/A";
            Title = "Game of Thrones: A Telltale Games Series";
            Type = game;
            Year = 2014;
            imdbID = tt3391176;
        },
                {
            Poster = "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTU1MzU2MDE4MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTc3NzA2MDE@._V1_SX300.jpg";
            Title = "Game of Thrones: Season 2 - Character Profiles";
            Type = movie;
            Year = 2013;
            imdbID = tt2653342;
        },
                {
            Poster = "N/A";
            Title = "Game of Thrones: A Day in the Life";
            Type = movie;
            Year = 2015;
            imdbID = tt4437700;
        },
                {
            Poster = "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTc5MjM4OTkzMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzc3NzA2MDE@._V1_SX300.jpg";
            Title = "Game of Thrones: Season 2 - Invitation to the Set";
            Type = movie;
            Year = 2012;
            imdbID = tt2653340;
        },
                {
            Poster = "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYyODg1MjYzMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTc3NzA2MDE@._V1_SX300.jpg";
            Title = "Game of Thrones: Costumes";
            Type = movie;
            Year = 2011;
            imdbID = tt2653350;
        },
                {
            Poster = "N/A";
            Title = "Game of Thrones: You Win or You Die - Inside the HBO Series";
            Type = movie;
            Year = 2012;
            imdbID = tt2972984;
        },
                {
            Poster = "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NzY5NDE1Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODc3NzA2MDE@._V1_SX300.jpg";
            Title = "Game of Thrones: Season 2 - How to Be an Extra";
            Type = movie;
            Year = 2012;
            imdbID = tt2653338;
        },
                {
            Poster = "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTgzNjYxNjY3NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTg3NzA2MDE@._V1_SX300.jpg";
            Title = "Game of Thrones: Inside the Night's Watch";
            Type = movie;
            Year = 2011;
            imdbID = tt2653352;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Getting data Synchronously is not recommended. Although use of `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` could be the fix that is doing the trick here.

Comment: @maulik app getting crash `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
`

Comment: Because i get response in console

Comment: yes the response is correct.but why i cant get that

Comment: Can you Give me .h and .m file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95905/discussion-between-mark-and-maulik-patel).

Comment: @MaulikPatel if possible please try to give some solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831496/need-to-show-the-image-of-video-in-mpmovieplayercontroller-swift

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use GET for getting response from server just you can try in following method

```
//First give your URL here
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Game%20of%20Thrones&Season=1"]];

//Set GET method for getting Response
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

//setValue and HTTPHeaderField here
[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

NSError *err;

NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request   returningResponse:&response error:&err];

//Now you need to check response.Once you get the response,copy that and paste in ONLINE JSON VIEWER(google this or type online json viewer in google). 

//Paste the response and click the Viewer.

//Set whether it is DICTIONARY(if it starts with {}json) or ARRAY(if it starts with []json),depends upon the json result.

NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

           //OR           

NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
```

Comment: that above solution solved my problem. i ned to update some thing in info.plist

Comment: I will tell you now what you have to add in Plist.Add + and Enter the name of the group: App Transport Security
Right click on the group and select Add Row
Enter Allow Arbitrary Loads
Set the value on the right to YES

Comment: If my answer helpful for you please up vote my answer.

Comment: Mark my answer also gives result.Check it.

Comment: if possible please try to give some solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831496/need-to-show-the-image-of-video-in-mpmovieplayercontroller-swift